# SQLite removing reference on rebuild

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

SQL Lite states that its added support for Xamrian Forms and .net standard and yet when I rebuild my project all references disappear what it the correct library I need to get SQL lite working in .net standard 2.0 I am using it to sync between a mobile app and the server.

```
public  async Task SyncAllDeliverys()
{
        Task<string> callTask = Task.Run(() => GetDeliverysFromAPi());
        // Wait for it to finish
        callTask.Wait();
        // Get the result
        string content = callTask.Result;

        //Sends a GET request to the specified Uri and returns the response body as a string in an asynchronous operation
        deliverysItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeliverysItems>>(content); //Deserializes or converts JSON String into a collection of Post
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        await conn.InsertAllAsync(deliverysItems);
}
```

[image]

As you see here my project is .net standard 2.0

[image: e]

**Edit 2**

To show the correct version that I have installed instead of the incorrect one I showed in the first graphic.

[image]

**Edit 2**
It would appear that this is a known bug and xamrian has submitted it as such in 2019 visual studio.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5983

Answer (score -1):

You are looking at the **wrong** description of dependencies. The dependencies in the first screenshot(you circled in the right bottom) belongs to **sqlite-net-pcl** instead of **SQLite.Net-PCL**.

> Package 'SQLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.

You can try uninstall and install `sqlite-net-pcl` nuget, clean and rebuild your project.

> what it the correct library I need to get SQL lite working in .net
>   standard 2.0

Use `sqlite-net-pcl` is the right way. (The fourth library in your screenshot).

There are a number of NuGet packages with similar names, the correct package has these attributes:

- Created by: **Frank A. Krueger**
- Id: **sqlite-net-pcl**
- NuGet link: [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)

Refer: [databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases)

Comment: If you look at my screen shot 1.5 is the one I have already installed its the one that keeps removing itself.

Comment: Please see my edit 2 this does not work its this one is not working at all it just disapears after reinstall.

Comment: Yes I did see the version 1.5. I also see you circled the SQLite.Net-PCL in the first screen shot and I think maybe you have looked a wrong description. I just tried reinstall sqlite-net-pcl on my side and it works well. You can try Restore nuget package or delete bin and obj folder, rebuild again your project.

Comment: in .net standard 2.0 and not pcl /

Comment: please see my edit above xmarian have admited this is a bug in 2019

Comment: @rogue39nin Ok, follow that issue and they will provide support to you.